# Using DECODE to compare multiple columns and return single value

Tags: oracle

I need help with a Oracle SQL statement. I need to compare 3 columns in a variety of ways and return one number.

Example:
Column A is Null & Column B is Null then return Column C
Column B is NULL & Column C is Null then Return Column A
Column A is Null & Column C is Null Then Return Column B
Column A is < Column B then Column A

and so on and so on.

I've tried CASE/WHEN/ELSE and DECODE(Trim. LEAST works ok when I'm comparing the 3 columns AS LONG AS they are NOT NULL or I get a 0.

I found the COALESCE(NULLIF statement and that worked great except for when I have multiple columns with values OVER 0 it is always returning the first value. Can I also add a "Least" function within (or at the end) of the NULLIF function so that it if 2 of the columns are NOT NULL then compare those 2 and give me the smallest value.

**Desired Results:**

```
desc      hrs   cyc     days    interval    hrs/cyc/days
============================================================
Task 1    72    0       0       72          hrs  
Task 2    2400  1200    2190    2400        hrs  
Task 3    600   0       180     600         hrs  
Task 4    0     500     120     500         cyc  
Task 5    0     0       30      30          day
```

The coding to get the above results in Business Intelligence/Web Intelligence is as follows:

```
= If  ( [Remain Hours]=0  And   [Remain Cycles]  = 0) Then [Schedule Days]  
Else If ([Remain Cycles]=0 And [Remain Days]= 0) Then [Schedule Hours]  
Else If ([Remain Hours]  = 0 And [Remain Days] = 0 ) Then [Schedule Cycles]  
Else If ([Remain Hours]  = 0 And ([Remain Days] < [Remain Cycles]/6 ) ) Then [Schedule Days]  
Else If ([Remain Hours]  = 0 And ( [Remain Cycles]/6 < [Remain Days]   ) ) Then [Schedule Cycles]  
Else If ([Remain Hours]  = 0 And ( [Remain Cycles]/6 > [Remain Days]   ) ) Then [Schedule Days]  
Else If ([Remain Cycles]  = 0 And ([Remain Hours]/13 < [Remain Days] ) ) Then [Schedule Hours]  
Else If ([Remain Cycles]  = 0 And ([Remain Hours]/13 > [Remain Days] ) ) Then [Schedule Days]  
Else If ([Remain Days]  = 0 And ( [Remain Hours]/13 < [Remain Cycles]/6   ) ) Then [Schedule Hours]  
Else If ([Remain Days]  = 0 And ( [Remain Hours]/13 > [Remain Cycles]/6   ) ) Then [Schedule Cycles]  
Else If  ( ([Remain Hours]/13)  < ([Remain Cycles]/6)  And  ( [Remain Hours]/13 < [Remain Days])  )  Then [Schedule Hours]  
Else If ( ([Remain Cycles]/6 < [Remain Days])  And ( [Remain Cycles]/6 < [Remain Hours]/13) ) Then [Schedule Cycles]  
Else If ( ( [Remain Days] < [Remain Cycles]/6 )  And ( [Remain Days] < [Remain Hours]/13) ) Then [Schedule Days]
```

Comment: Please post some sample data and desired result

Comment: Can you describe the bigger problem you are trying to solve?  I suspect this is part of a bigger solution, where if we had the bigger picture we may be able to offer a better solution.

Comment: Yes I will. Basically I work for an airline and create their maintenance reports. Each maintenance task is driven to be done by either the hours, cycles and/or days of that task - which ever comes first. These values are stored in 3 different fields. So, task A is has all 3 fields that it is tracked. I know I can convert the HOURS & CYCLES to DAYS but I need it to compare all 3 columns IF ANY IS NOT NULL and give me the smallest value.

Comment: task A            Hours           cycles          Days                                             check oil          50                35                15                                                divide hours 50/13=4 (days equivalent of hrs); devide cycles 35/6= 6 (days equivalent of cycles). It needs to compare the previous 2 results to the DAYS field and then return the smallest ORIGINAL (what is in the table field) value. IF 2 of the fields are NULL then return the 3rd value. BUT of 2 or more of the fields is NOT NULL then it needs to do the above comparison. Does that help??

Comment: One more question - how do you add a "table" format in this thing??? :)

Comment: You'd be better off editing your original post as the comment section does not allow for formatting.  Look right under the tags area of the post and you'll see an `edit` link.

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand, you want to select the lowest value from all 3 columns, but some of the columns can be null and the order of the values in the columns is not necessarily ascending.

Assuming that *at least* 1 column has a non-null value, this will work for you:

```
SELECT LEAST(COALESCE(COL_A, 2147483647), COALESCE(COL_B, 2147483647), COALESCE(COL_C, 2147483647))
FROM YOUR_TABLE
```

`2147483647` is the max possible value of a PLS_INTEGER. Presumably all of your real values will be much less than this max value and the `LEAST` function will return the lowest value in any column.

You will have a problem if *all three* columns can be null though since this will return `2147483647` for the result. In that case, you can do a `DECODE` to ignore the value and return `NULL` instead:

```
SELECT DECODE(LEAST(COALESCE(COL_A, 2147483647), COALESCE(COL_B, 2147483647), COALESCE(COL_C, 2147483647)), 2147483647, NULL)
FROM YOUR_TABLE
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion unfortunately both statements return NULL for the entire column. Any other suggestions???